# Can the term ちわ be used as slang for こんにちわ？

Tags: word-choice, slang, internet-slang

The term was used in a chat and I can't find the meaning.

Comment: http://monjiro.net/dic/rank/34/138569/39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ちわ is an abbreviated form of こんにちわ, when written using hiragana。

Comment: You can turn comments of other people into answers, but unless you expand them, it's probably considered good style to make them "community wiki", which is a type of answer other people can edit as well. This way the original commenter as well as other people can add to them. (You find the community wiki check mark on the right side under the text input when you post/edit an answer.)

Comment: @Earthliŋ, Thank you very much. As the expresssion was used in a chat posting, I was subsequently able to clarify the expression with another user.

Answer (score 0):

In many Japanese words we can't tell what a word means unless it is written in kanji because there are many homonyms. It could be a girl's name, but it could also mean a conversation between a couple. For example, if it is 痴話げんか, it means "An argument between a couple". Hope that helped.